# How to wrap C 2D arrays (Foo**) in C++ code?

Tags: c++, c, stl, wrapper

I use a C library which operates on 2D arrays in the form of Foo**. I use it inside C++ code, so I need some sort of wrapper. With 1D arrays it's straightforward because vector iterators are just pointers, but in case of 2D it gets more complicated. Is it possible to make a wrapper for Foo** without copying the data?

Comment: Do you want to feed your C library with a STL container (converting it to `Foo**`), or do you want to build a STL container out of a `Foo**` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The elements of a `vector<Foo>` are stored in a dynamically allocated contiguous memory, so you can get a pointer `Foo*` to the array, as you do in your first case.

But the elements of a nested vector `vector<vector<Foo> >` are not stored as a contiguous 2D array, so you can't get a `Foo**` directly.

You could try something like this :

```
vector<vector<Foo> > data;
vector<Foo*> data_rows;
for(auto it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); ++it) {
    //in c++11, you can use data() instead of casting begin()
    data_rows.push_back(it->data());
}
Foo** c_data = data_rows.data();
```

That way you're not copying the data, just the row pointers.

Comment: Yuou should probably use `vector<Foo*>` as a target, rather than memory allocated with malloc, that's a bit more C++y. You can then do `vec.data()` to get a `Foo**`.

Answer (score 1):

I would propose to build a class overriding `operator []`, which holds the C pointer Foo** internally.

E.g.:

```
template <class T>
class Mat<T> {
private: T** ptr; int n; int m; //< 2D array is of size n x m
public: Mat( int n, int m ) : n(n), m(m) {}
Col<T> operator[]( int k ) { assert(k<n); return Col<T>(*(ptr+k*n)); }
T& get(int k, int i ) { return *(*(ptr+k*n)+i); }
}
```

having defined

```
template <class T>
class Col<T> { private: T* ptr;
public: T& operator[]( int i ) { return *(ptr+i); }
Col<T>(T* ptr) : ptr(ptr) { }
}
```

The code may not be 100% correct, but i hope you get the point and can reimplement it.
Also make sure livetime of pointerdata exceeds your c++ wrapper (also wrap the refcount mechanism of the c library?).
The nice point of `operator[]` is, that now you can use it like that:

```
Foo** ptr = from_some_c_library();
Mat<Foo> mat(ptr,3,4);
Foo& element_at_2_2 = mat[2][2];
assert( mat.get(2,2) == mat[2][2] );
```

Note that you may want to implement custom iterators for `Mat<T>` to make it work with STL functions.